# Why is `this` binded to window?

Tags: coffeescript

I need to get a href value after click. My code looks like this:

```
$('.menu a').click (event) =>
  event.preventDefault()
  console.log($(this).attr('href')) # it returns 'undefined'
```

What am I doing wrong?

[edited]

My html code:

```
<div class="menu">
    <a href="/all/">All</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Does the element have an `href` attribute?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with CoffeeScript, but when I add `console.log($(this))`, it's logging the `window`, not the `a` element I click on.

Comment: Thanks for help :) It was problem with coffee script method arrows! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of the subtle difference in Coffeescript between `=>` and `->`

> In JavaScript, the this keyword is dynamically scoped to mean the
>   object that the current function is attached to. If you pass a
>   function as a callback or attach it to a different object, the
>   original value of this will be lost. If you're not familiar with this
>   behavior, [this Digital Web article](http://www.digital-web.com/articles/scope_in_javascript/) gives a good overview of the
>   quirks.
>
> The **fat arrow =>** can be used to both define a function, **and to bind it
>   to the current value of this**, right on the spot. This is helpful when
>   using callback-based libraries like Prototype or jQuery, for creating
>   iterator functions to pass to each, or event-handler functions to use
>   with bind. Functions created with the fat arrow are able to access
>   properties of the this where they're defined.
>
> http://coffeescript.org/

This is why `this` is binded to window.

You should use:

```
$('.menu a').click (event) ->
  event.preventDefault()
  console.log($(this).attr('href')) # it returns the link !
```